# wxPython - how to import the wx.adv module?

Tags: wxpython

Trying to work with wx.adv according to http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/adv.1classindex.html
But I'm getting "ImportError: No module named adv".

Is there an installer or a special way to import it? Is it deprecated...?

Using Windows and Mac, Python 2.7.6, wxPython 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you *think* you have Phoenix/are running Phoenix, but are in fact not?

Try on the command line (sorry, tested on windows, but should apply to Mac too):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'2.9.5.0 msw (classic)'
```

as opposed to

```
'3.0.1.dev76380 msw (phoenix)'
```

in a virtualenv with 2.7.6 and Phoenix. Which class do you want to use? As stated, `wx.adv` is Phoenix, classic does not have `wx.adv` out of the box and the things may be in other places.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the difference. Thanks for that! I've found what I need now wx.gizmos.EditableListBox instead of wx.adv.EditableListBox!

Comment: @user1248826 at the end of http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html you find a list of old/new location of what is in Phoenix in wx.adv

Comment: @Werner: Again learned something! I knew your cited link (classic vs. Phoenix) already, but deemed it not helpful, because it gives the direction classic->Phoenix, but not the other way round. But if you do a search on the page, you get also that (``wx.gizmos``, hidden on the bottom of the page, though).