# Can't import wx.adv from wxPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am running Python3.8.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 with wxPython version `4.1.0 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.4`. I cannot use it in a project I have cloned as I get the following error:

```
   import wx.adv
ImportError: No module named adv
```

I installed wxPython according to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073145/how-to-install-wxpython-4-ubuntu-18-04) and the setup did not fail. I am sure I have wxPython as I run it in the Python shell and see the version mentioned above. The only other relevant question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102834/wxpython-how-to-import-the-wx-adv-module) but that problem was classic vs. phoenix, which I have the right type (phoenix).

Does anyone know why the module `adv` specifically cannot be found?

Comment: sometime in the past the advanced library was merged into the core. So if you look into the wx Git master, you won't see it. I don't know what wx version is your specific wxPython version is built on, but for C++ it is still symlinked to some empty library, so not to break existing code. You may bring it up on the wxPython forum/ML. My guess is that the script that creates wxPython doesn't handle this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
According to the docs (https://wxpython.org/pages/changes/index.html) it should still be working fine for my version as they have even been adding more functionality to it.

Comment: agreed - it should. However - it doesn't. Do you see the module itself in the place you installed wxPython? Can you successfully import wx?

Comment: Yes, I can. I even manually went and added it to my PYTHONPATH in ~/.bashrc. Running the Python shell, I see that I can `import wx` and `wx.version()` yields the above version. However, I noticed I have two packages for it: `wx` and `wxPython-4.1.0-py3.8.egg-info`. Could it be looking in the wrong package?

Comment: quite possible. Can you remove wxpython and python and then install it a-fresh?

Comment: I just made it work. Instead of running the script that does everything (as given to me in this large project), I manually ran the files needed to start the application. It somehow worked like that... Thank you for your help!

Comment: except that you will need to run it as packaged software...

Comment: Are you using wxpython "Classic" or "Phoenix"?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102834/wxpython-how-to-import-the-wx-adv-module